# Flexible table where 2 cells collapse into one

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am making a table with inputs and I ran into the challenge of needing to collapse two cells into one when the screen size decreases without duplicating the content of the cell that collapses. In other words, I want to use only media queries and CSS to collapse the two cells without duplicating the cells content. I would rather only use media queries than programmatically edit the DOM.

To be more specific, I don't want this:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col" className="py-3.5 pl-4 pr-3 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 sm:pl-0">
      Name
  </th>
  <th
    scope="col"
    className="hidden px-3 py-3.5 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 lg:table-cell"
  >
    Title
  </th>
  <th
    scope="col"
    className="hidden px-3 py-3.5 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 sm:table-cell"
  >
    Email
  </th>
</thead>
<tbody className="divide-y divide-gray-200 bg-white">
  <tr>
    <td className="w-full max-w-0 py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:w-auto sm:max-w-none sm:pl-0">
      My Name
      <dl className="font-normal lg:hidden">
        <dt className="sr-only">Title</dt>
        <dd className="mt-1 truncate text-gray-700">My Duplicated Title</dd>
        <dt className="sr-only sm:hidden">My Duplicated Email</dt>
        <dd className="mt-1 truncate text-gray-500 sm:hidden">{person.email}</dd>
      </dl>
    </td>
    <td className="hidden px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500 lg:table-cell">My Title</td>
    <td className="hidden px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500 sm:table-cell">My Email</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

(I'm using tailwind and react by the way.)

Instead, I want a way of collapsing cells onto one another without having to duplicate the content of the collapsed cell. My last resort would be to use window.matchMedia.

The reason not wanting to duplicate content is that I am using an input field that cannot be duplicated. I hope I made sense.

Comment: Yes, it sort of makes sense what you want to do. I don't think you can merge two table cells with CSS. You need to find another solution.

Comment: Should I use something else like grid or flexbox to make my table?

Comment: Perhaps I could understand what you are wanting if you included images of the current and desired result. If you don't want "My Duplicated Title" and "My Duplicated Email" to be visible, use `display: none` in the appropriate media query.

Comment: A bit of an explanation: With CSS you can only show, hide, or even _visually_ move, HTML tags (= [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)), you cannot change the underlying DOM structure itself. CSS takes the DOM and tells the browser how to present it. Whatever you choose, keep this in mind. Sorry, I cannot make this choice for you.

Comment: You may give a try with `display`  for cells you want to merge into the same column. Try for example these class : `md:table-cell block` with 2 sibbling cells ... they will come on top of each others. Do not draw borders or background from them, but you could use tr and col elements : example to play with https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/NWogRqr

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As G-Cyrillus has stated, the solution was to make the `<td>` have the classes `md:table-cell block`.

Here are some screenshots:

Large:

[image: large screen width screenshot]

Small:

[image: small screen width screenshot]

Very ugly tables but I'll fix that!

Answer (score 1):

To complete @AlanGanser  answer, i put here the example given in the comments that helped him to sort it out.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h1>resize the view to go down to 2 columns ... or go to fullpage to see the 3 cols if already shrinked down.</h1>
<div class="mx-32">
  <table class="w-full px-32 bg-yellow-400">
    <colgroup>
      <col class="border-solid border-current border-2" />
      <col class="bg-gray-400 border-solid border-current border-2" />
      <col class="border-solid border-current border-2" />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
      <tr class="border-solid border-current border-2">
        <th scope="col" class="py-3.5 pl-4 pr-3 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 sm:pl-0">
          Name
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class=" px-3 py-3.5 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 md:table-cell block">
          Title
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class=" px-3 py-3.5 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 md:table-cell block">
          Email
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="divide-y divide-gray-200 ">
      <tr class="border-solid border-current border-2">
        <td class="  max-w-0 py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:w-auto sm:max-w-none sm:pl-0">
          My Name
          <dl class="font-normal lg:hidden">
            <dt class="sr-only">Title</dt>
            <dd class="mt-1 truncate text-gray-700">My Duplicated Title</dd>
            <dt class="sr-only sm:hidden">My Duplicated Email</dt>
            <dd class="mt-1 truncate text-gray-500 sm:hidden">{person.email}</dd>
          </dl>
        </td>
        <td class=" px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500 md:table-cell block">My Title</td>
        <td class=" px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500 md:table-cell block">My Email</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

original codepen to play with: https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/NWogRqr